# Jenkins editable email notification attachment : Mail going without attachment

Tags: email, csv, jenkins

The jenkins editable email notification in sending the mail but without the attachment.The attachment is in the workspace of jenkins.Path of attachment `jenkins\workspace\projectname\test.csv`.In the Attachments field of the editable email notification i am specifying `projectname/test.csv` but the attachment is not getting send.
I have also tried `**/projectname/test.csv` ,`**/test.csv` , `/projectname` but nothing seems to work.

PS: File size is about 10MB.

Comment: The base directory for attachment field is the workspace. Did you try `projectname/test.csv` ?

Comment: yes I tried that but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the "Email-ext plugin". more information is available here :                            https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 0):

I used a added a execute shell to the build moving (cd) to the directory of the file and then coping (cp) the file to the workspace directory, i them rename (mv) it and then attach it.